# Deploying existing PHP app from Github not recognising enviroment

Tags: php, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my PHP app hosted on github to heroku. Unfortunately heroku doesn't recognise it as PHP and uses default Nodejs setup. I made sure i have composer file in the root directory as specified by heroku documentation page. I also copied Procfile from their example app. Wonder if anybody have an idea why heroku doesn't recognise my app as PHP?

**UPDATE**

If i push the project from my machine directly to heroku, everything works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a ticket with heroku support revealed that once my app was recognised as nodejs wouldn't change automatically to PHP (I had a package.json file in my project which made it to look like nodejs app to heroku, and removing it wouldn't help). Simply creating new heroku app, without package.json file solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct buildpack before pushing to heroku:

`heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php`

does the trick.